# Require interface to have all properties from enum

Tags: typescript, enums, interface, type-mapping

Is there any way to force a Typescript interface to implement all keys of an enum? My code is as follows:

```
export enum Setting {
    START_TIME = 'START_TIME_DB_KEY',
    END_TIME = 'END_TIME_DB_KEY',
    COOL_FEATURE = 'COOL_FEATURE_DB_KEY',
    SOME_EXPIRY_SETTING = 'SOME_EXPIRY_DB_KEY',
}

export type RequireAllKeys = { [key in Setting]: any; };

export interface SettingsTypeMap extends RequireAllKeys {
    [Setting.START_TIME]: number;
    [Setting.END_TIME]: number;
    [Setting.COOL_FEATURE]: boolean;
    [Setting.SOME_EXPIRY_SETTING]: Date;
}
```

What I want is that my `SettingsTypeMap` throws an error if it's missing one of the enum keys, e.g. if it looks like this:

```
export interface SettingsTypeMap extends RequireAllKeys {
    [Setting.START_TIME]: number;
}
```

it should throw an error saying something like "interface is missing properties `Setting.END_TIME, Setting.COOL_FEATURE, Setting.SOME_EXPIRY_SETTING`".

Comment: Just `type SettingsTypeMap = { [key in Setting]: number; };` Why do you want to retype all the keys?

Comment: Because I want to map each key to a certain type (not all to the same type). I've edited my post to highlight this.

Comment: OK, I see. But if you'll just define `interface SettingsTypeMap { [Setting.START_TIME]: number; }` (without extends) - you won't be able to access any setting until it explicitly defined in this type. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Well, maybe it'll have to be enough, but I my question is whether or not it's possible to enforce implementation of all the keys in the type map :)

Comment: The thing is - it is **not** implementation. Implementation is a class for example and it will require to fill all the props

Comment: Declaration, then. So there's no way to enforce it?

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense on type level